# Hack responsive para M. Edge

Tags: css, css3

pregunta corta.
Este hack es para M. Edge

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
       div {
         display:inline-flex;
    }
}
```

Como puedo usar este hack en responsive?. O sea que en @media este este hack para M. Edge como display:inline-table

Gracias a tod qs

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta:

Mete la declaración `@support` dentro de `@media`:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

  @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    div {
      display: inline-table;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pero esto lo probe ayer y no funcionaba....hmmm

Comment: @DarioB. - Y lo haz probado hoy? :) ...en verdad no te debería dar ningún problema...  avísame si sigue sin funcionar

Comment: -Me funciono perfecto, gracias de verdad.